# react-navigation fails to show a screen added in StackNavigator

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

React-Native beginner here. I am trying to make StackNavigation work with TabNavigation in React-Native with Typescript. There are three screens in my app. `FirstScreen` and `SecondScreen` are displayed as tabs where as `PopScreen` is shown when "Click Here" button in `FirstScreen` is clicked. `this.props.navigation.navigate("Pop")` call on button click seems to have failed without any error, however it returns `false`.

Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, Button } from "react-native";
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { TabNavigator, NavigationStackScreenOptions } from 'react-navigation';

class FirstScreen extends React.Component<any, any> {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>My First Tab Screen!!!</Text>
                <Button 
                    title="Click Here"
                    onPress={ () => this.props.navigation.navigate("Pop"); } />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

class SecondScreen extends React.Component<any, any> {
    render() {
        return (
            <Text>My Second Tab Screen</Text>
        );
    }
}

class PopScreen extends React.Component<any, any> {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Content in pop up.</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const TabOptions = TabNavigator({
    MyFirst: { screen : FirstScreen },
    MySecond: { screen : SecondScreen }
});

class TabOptionsScreen extends React.Component<any, any>
{
    static navigationOptions : NavigationStackScreenOptions = {
        header: null
    };

    render() {
        return ( <TabOptions /> )
    }
}

export const App = StackNavigator ({
   Home : {  screen: TabOptionsScreen },
   Pop: { screen: PopScreen }
})
```

`this.props.navigation` object is not null or undefined in `FirstScreen` class but somehow it doesn't recognize the options passed in StackNavigator. Please help me how can I make `navigate` method work in any of children screens of TabNavigator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few reads, I came to realize that `this.props.navigator` is exclusive to the Navigator in which it is being used. `navigator` in TabNavigator can be used to switch between tabs, and `navigator` in StackNavigator can push the screen in or pop it from screens' stack. Screens in navigator do inherit `navigator` object from parent, but they are not passed deep down in screens hierarchy. So there are two solutions:

First solution is almost same as suggested by Guilherme, but in stead of passing `navigationOptions` in TabNavigator, I passed it in StackNavigator with associated screen.

```
const TabOptions = TabNavigator({
    MyFirst: { screen : FirstScreen },
    MySecond: { screen : SecondScreen }
});
// TabOptionsScreen class removed here. 
// TabOptions constant is directly passed in StackNavigator.
export const App = StackNavigator ({
    Home : {  
       screen: TabOptions,
       navigationOptions : {
            header: null
        }
    },
    Pop: { screen: PopScreen }
})
```

And now I can use `this.props.navigation.navigate("Pop")` in FirstScreen component. It also allows us to navigate to other tabs available at same level - `this.props.navigation.navigate("MySecond")`.

In my original code, I wrote all screens in separate files, and I wanted to keep `navigationOptions` of screen in its own class definition. So second solution regards this modular approach.

```
export class FirstScreen extends React.Component<any, any> {
    render() {
        const { navigate } = this.props.screenProps.navigation;
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>My First Tab Screen!!!</Text>
                <Button 
                    title="Click Here !!!"
                    onPress={ () => navigate("Pop") }/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const TabOptions = TabNavigator({
    MyFirst: { screen : FirstScreen },
    MySecond: { screen : SecondScreen }
});

export class TabOptionsScreen extends React.Component<any, any>
{
    static navigationOptions : NavigationStackScreenOptions = {
        header: null,
    };

    render() {
        return ( <TabOptions screenProps={{ navigation: this.props.navigation }} /> )
    }
}

export const App = StackNavigator ({
   Home : {  screen: TabOptionsScreen },
   Pop: { screen: PopScreen }
})
```

In this code, `TabOptionsScreen` is direct child of `StackNavigator`, so `navigation` object is also passed down to it, but now we have to manually pass `navigation` object in `TabOptions` navigator. `screenProps` can be used for passing props from parent component to child. In `FirstScreen`, use `this.props.screenProps.navigation` for stack navigation, and `this.props.navigation` for tab navigation.